# PHP - Go back to previous URL after login with Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cookies, facebook-login

I have created a facebook login using the tutorial from http://www.9lessons.info/2011/02/login-with-facebook-and-twitter.html. But the problem is after logging in the user will be redirected to the index.php page. How can i redirect him to the page from which he has clicked the login.

I tried saving the previous url to session. But i don't know why, its not working. It worked for normal login, but not for facebook. I also tried saving the previous url to cookie. It also didn't work. Url is saving, But after logging in session url/cookie url is lost. Can someone pls tell me an alternative method???

Comment: From what I understand, users will be redirected to whatever page you setup in the Facebook App settings.

Comment: @SanuelJackson No its not related to app. In the php page, its said to redirect to "home.php". I want to go to the page from where the user have clicked login. Suppose when the user clicked login from "page2.php", then after logging in he must be redirect to the same page, "page2.php"

Comment: Store the page they were on in a session/cookie, then redirect if that is set -- if it allows. I will post as an answer so I can give a code example for setting the session var, and handling the redirect -- won't be writing Facebook code tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example to store the current page

Do on all but your login page before redirect:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['lastpage'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

On all other pages :

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['lastpage'])) {
  $lastpage = $_SESSION['lastpage'];
  $_SESSION['lastpage'] = false;
  unset($_SESSION['lastpage']);
  header("location: " . $lastpage);
}
```

Something like that should work.  Make sure to santize the $_SESSION variable, and also validate the last URL was from your site (or supported site) before setting the session var.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I haven't tried it yet. But the code i used before is similar to it. Except i didn't make it false and unset it. Is that will be the problem??

Comment: @user3392772 - Unsetting it would be important to prevent infinite redirect loops.

Comment: ok. I used this method for normal login, it worked and redirected to the previous page. But implementing it with facebook, its not working. Because after authentication of facebook, the session variable is lost. I tried echo the session variable. Its showing empty

Comment: @user3392772 - is the page embedded in Facebook ? Can try switching `$_SESSION`, with `setcookie` and `$_COOKIE`

Comment: both worked well in pc. But not worked in mobile. Why is it so??

Comment: @user3392772 - I believe mobile will open the Facebook app when using it to authenticate, then the App will redirect or open the page inside the app, so it would be new --- I do not know the answer specifically for that, but I am glad this is working for you.

Comment: @GijoVarghese I am in a similar situation. Can you tell me what exactly did you do? Because when I set redirect URL to previous page the login stops working. I am using PHP SDK new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($weburl); << $weburl here is the url to previous page or the page the user came from

Comment: @SaadBashir have to tried the method in the answer?

Comment: Well instead of storing it in session i used variable. The result should be same no?

Comment: @SaadBashir - Variable storage is only viable if it is persisted and able to be loaded and associated with the same user when facebook redirects back to the same static landing page. Unfortunately, you can only have one static landing page to handle all logins and Facebook doesn't really return anything when starting the session for you to track. This is why you need to make up your own method, and sessions / cookies are the most viable methods for simplification. You could use browser storage as well, but this is more complex.